# How to find smallest and largest representable number possible given a Normalized Floating Point System

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point

Let's say you are given the normalized floating-point system:
$R_3(3, 1)$ with exponent range $−1 ≤ e ≤ 1$
The base is $3$, mantissa length is $3$ and exponent length is $1$.
How would you go about to find the smallest and largest positive number possible?

Comment: Does your textbook discuss the format of single/double precision numbers?

Comment: Not that I can find

Comment: The Wikipedia page for IEEE single/double precision is decent. Have a look at that and see if you can not obtain those results.